# google cloud storage lifecycle downgrade to nearline

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a regional bucket where we load a lot of files every day to different folders. After 30 days I want all these files to be downgraded to nearline. What happens when I set the gs lifecycle to downgrade objects to nearline after 30 days? Will a new bucket be created with the same folder structure with a nearline storage class? Or will the objects themselves have new storage class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects in the bucket will have their storage class changed.For more [details](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-storage-bucket-lifecycle)

Comment: ok great. So there will be files with mixed storage class in the bucket? I thought the storage class was for all files in the bucket.

Comment: yes there will be files with mixed storage class. Add objects to the bucket, will inherit the storage class of bucket unless explicitly set otherwise

Comment: Thanks. What would the best strategy be? To copy files to a bucket with nearline storage class or just letting the objects change storage class within the original regional bucket? Are there any pros/cons?

Comment: It depends, moving the objects would probably be more expensive as you might incur into a higher amount of operations which would mean a higher billing [according to this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-pricing). 

Meanwhile, if you just change the objects storage class, it may get trickier to handle the objects as you would have to be mindful of their storage class when reading them if they all live in the same place.